# MySQL query execution issue

Tags: mysql

This is my table content and structure:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`common` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `apps_names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



insert  into `apps_names`(`id`,`name`) values (1,'calendar'),(2,'conference'),(3,'lunch'),(4,'devices'),(5,'confluence'),(6,'jira'),(7,'newsletter'),(8,'fotbal'),(9,'svu'),(10,'radio'),(11,'meetings'),(12,'benefits'),(13,'common');


CREATE TABLE `apps_roles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_app` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_role` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


insert  into `apps_roles`(`id`,`id_app`,`id_role`) values (1,11,1),(2,11,2),(3,11,3),(4,11,4),(5,11,5),(6,11,6),(7,12,7),(8,12,8),(9,12,9),(10,12,10),(11,12,11),(12,12,12),(13,12,13),(14,8,2),(15,3,11),(16,4,15),(17,4,11);


CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


insert  into `roles`(`id`,`name`) values (1,'Angajat'),(2,'Administrator'),(3,'Team-Lead'),(4,'Project-Manager'),(5,'Line-Manager'),(6,'Department-Manager'),(7,'Benefits-Admin'),(8,'Events-Admin'),(9,'Fitnes-Admin'),(10,'Pensions-Admin'),(11,'Super-Admin'),(12,'Swim-Admin'),(13,'Fitness-and-Swim-Admin'),(15,'Sim-Admin');

CREATE TABLE `users_roles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


insert  into `users_roles`(`id`,`app_id`,`user_id`,`role_id`) values (1,11,1759,2),(2,11,1767,2);
```

and this is my query:

**UPDATE QUERY:**

```
 SELECT r.id, r.name , role_id, id_role, ur.user_id, ur.app_id ,ap.id_app FROM roles r 
INNER JOIN apps_roles ap ON 
r.id = ap.id_role 
LEFT JOIN users_roles ur
ON ur.role_id = ap.id_role

WHERE (user_id = '1759' OR user_id IS NULL ) AND id_app = '11'
```

I want to extract all of **role name**  and check it on which role id is assign an user. Also I want to get the null values. How do I do that ?

**UPDATE** This should be the wanted result:
[image]

Comment: of the ur.app_id. In the ur.app_id I will check later in php if the user have this role on the application  X, if it is null it means that the user x doesn't have role y in app x

Comment: so, anyone any idea? I would really appreaciate it :D

Comment: ON ur.app_id = r.id should be ur.app_id = ap.id_app should it not. You might want to consider your names id_app && app_id is confusing as 'erm heck

Comment: please check my post again, now with your suggest i did not get the null value, as you can see in the image, I got the number 11 everywhere. Thx for trying to help me, i realy appreciate it :)

Comment: JN ever use sql fiddle ?

Comment: I really wanted, but after 2 minutes of waiting i got this error message:" a timeout occurred on a exclusive lock with name" :(. I tried in other browser, but I got the same result

Comment: PLEASE CHECK MY POST AGAIN. I made some update !!